# Problem to shutdown from wingpanel

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, updates, shutdown

When I click over shutdown on wingpanel nothing happens. It started two days ago after updating. The only way to shutdown is opening a terminal and run`sudo shutdown -h now` 
Any advise?

Translated from:

Al clickear sobre el icono de un botón, por ejemplo, shutdown, este no se ejecuta, queda fijo sin ejecutar la funcion para la que fue creado. Esta situación ha sucedido últimamente, pero hasta antes de ayer, funcionaba bien. Al parecer esto sucedió con las últimas actualizaciones. De todas maneras para apagarlo tengo que abrir el Terminal y apagar el equipo con el comando sudo shutdown -h now. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command

```
pkill wingpanel
```

in a terminal window or with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to restart stuck wingpanel.